# Display HighStock y-axis and its labels on the right of the series

Tags: highcharts

Take a look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/P8hrN/

```
$(function() {

$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true

    }],


        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1,
            inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

});

I use "opposite: true" to display the y-axis on the right. But I want also the labels (numbers) to be on the right of the axis, not inside the series area.
At the moment, the numbers are on the left, so the series touches the "450" label.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `align:'left'`, so anchor-point for label will be on a left side. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P8hrN/1/) and [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.labels.align).

Comment: Oh, this does work, it just doesn't make any sense! It happens only for stockcharts...